# Disable error logging in typo3

Tags: typo3

I need to disable all error and warning logging in typo3.
How can I do that?

I tried to set this in localconf.php

```
$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['SYS']['displayErrors'] = 0;
$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['SYS']['syslogErrorReporting'] = 0;
$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['SYS']['belogErrorReporting'] = 0;
```

But it doesn't seems to work

Comment: I think this would be better suited for webmasters or serverfault ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's **global_localconf.php**? That must be some custom setup, right?

You can add the settings to **typo3conf/localconf.php** either manually or via the install tool (http://www.example.com/typo3/install/index.php?TYPO3_INSTALL[type]=extConfig).

Otherwise, the display of PHP warnings/errors (that's what `$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['SYS']['displayErrors']` sets) can be altered in the **.htaccess** file (in the root of your website):

```
php_flag display_errors off
```

Answer (score 3):

Thought I just write the full answer for disabling all logging:

**localconf.php**

```
$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['SYS']['displayErrors'] = '0';
$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['SYS']['devIPmask'] = '';
$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['SYS']['errorHandler'] = '';
$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['SYS']['debugExceptionHandler'] = '';
$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['SYS']['productionExceptionHandler'] = '';
$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['SYS']['systemLog'] = '';
$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['SYS']['enable_errorDLOG'] = '0';
$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['SYS']['enable_exceptionDLOG'] = '0';
$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['SYS']['enableDeprecationLog'] = '0';
```

**.htaccess**

```
php_flag display_errors off
php_flag log_errors off
```

Comment: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/CoreApiReference/6.1/ErrorAndExceptionHandling/Configuration/Examples/